# How to hide links on browser's statusbar when you mouseover on links on webpage?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, statusbar

I am using Zend, PHP, AJAX, JQuery in my projects. Question is that how can I force to not display a link on browser's statusbar when I mouseover on a link on my webpage.

Best example is on this site, when you mouseover the up-vote link on this site, it does not show the link and after click the votes increased without refreshing the page.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't do that. Very few people will notice except those who will be annoyed by the non-standard behaviour. If you did manage to hide it, users could still get the information through other methods.

Comment: I thought it is good for security purpose, when you click up-vote link, link does not appear at any place and the vote is stored in database. anyway thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, you don't see an address, because it isn't a link (i.e. it isn't an anchor). It is a span, image or other element, with an onclick event handler.

This is the only way to guarantee no status-bar text in all browsers as the old-school JavaScript method of setting window.status = ""; has no effect in most browsers these days.

So, for example...

```
[Html]
<img id="clickme" src="myimage.png" alt="My Image" title="Vote">

[JavaScript (jQuery)]
$("#clickme").click(function() { alert("You clicked me"); });
```

Answer (score 7):

Older browsers had something like `window.status = "";` where you could send messages to the status bar, and likewise effectively hide normal messages.

This is no longer supported on most browsers.

So, if you use a hyperlink - or more specifically an anchor element `<a>` - with an `href` attribute, there's no getting around the status bar.

If you check out the HTML for SO, you'll see the vote up "link" isn't a link at all but an image with some javascript event handlers assigned to the `onclick` event.

So why is that the cursor turns into that pointed finger when you mouse over the "vote up"? That's because of the CSS `cursor` property.

```
.vote img {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

That CSS comes out of the 'all.css' stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

The status bar highlighting happens only when you use an `<a>` element with a set `href`.

If you use pure JavaScript to open your link, and don't assign a `href` attribute, nothing will turn up in the status bar.

Comment: … and you'll be violating rule 2: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Comment: True, but depending on scenario, it may not matter to the OP. I don't see a reliable way of doing this without violating a rule.

Answer (score 0):

if you can see (view source ), the vote up link on the side is not a link, it is an image. If you click on it, it fires an ajax function call on this link, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2207467/vote/, which updates the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well... maybe it's not the best way but it works:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="location.href='your_url'">Click me!</a>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('yoururl')">Open in window</a>
```

Inside the tag you can put an image or something else, also you can call some function in the onclick and then inside it call AJAX and have the URL OR process in the backend, which I believe is the case (a process), not exactly navigating to another page, because that new page would be obvious in the address bar...

Hope this helps!