# How do you hide the URL when you hover a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, css

When you hover over a hyperlink you see in the corner of your browser the url you're gonig to. I'm using javascript to navigate through my tabs div. When I hover over the tab I see the url. I would like to hide this. Is this possible?

[image: example]

[Link to example](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/8427/schermafbeelding2011071f.png)

Comment: Are you sure you really want to hide the URL? Smart users will be suspicious about where you are sending them, and may not click at all. I wouldn't.

Comment: is there a reason you want to hide it?

Comment: You can use an onclick added to a SPAN element and use javascript to manipulate your address. If the purpose is to obscure where the user is being sent, I'd also advocate using some caution.

Comment: This question is (almost) a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207467/how-to-hide-links-on-browsers-statusbar-when-you-mouseover-on-links-on-webpage

Comment: I would encourage you to ask this as a question on [programmers.se] about why you wouldn't want to do this. You'll find that most developers are going to discourage you from doing this, so you may want to figure out a good reason why it should be done. Around 1999 there was a habit of making the area where the URL shows into a marquee, but that was often subverted to do malicious things to users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use the "href" attribute, the link won't show up.

Simply do this:
`<a id="tab1">Tab 1</a>`

`$('#tab1').click(function(event) {
  switchTabs();
});`

This will register a click event (using jQuery) on the link without displaying any URL to the user.  This is the proper way for handling links that don't redirect the user.

Comment: Thanks you! This was where I was looking for.

Comment: @WillMulligan Thank you Will for actually answering the question instead of telling him what he shouldn't even try to do.  You guys have no idea if he is doing something nefarious or his client might have even made this a requirement.  Way to go SO Question Nazis.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it!  Clients like to see where links are going.  This behavior isn't up to you.

The only thing you could reasonably do is set the link to go to nowhere, and set the `onclick` attribute with sourcecode that does a `window.location`.

Comment: I think it depends on the application. For instance, Gmail uses this technique (with Ajax) when loading your mail into view. I'm not sure anyone is claiming that's dangerous.

Comment: @Jared: ajax by definition stays on the same page so there is no link url. this is not gmail specific.

Comment: @yi_H - My point was not about Gmail or Ajax, but about application (my point was that they use SPANs to load new content, but don't show you a URL when doing so). It's probably not worth the effort (in my opinion), but we cannot necessarily predict that in every case it should not be done. My opinion is it should be done with caution. :)

Comment: and my point was that it's AJAX, so why would they show a url? you only do that for search bots, which doesn't make sense for gmail.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="javascript:RedirectToUrl(0)">Hide Text</a>`

Then in that function you can have a switch case statement which uses `window.location` to send the user to another page.

Downsides to this include alienating your users which disable Javascript, and search engines probably won't follow this link.

Comment: "can't follow this link" also, this is bad juju. Just use jQuery and bind to the class'ed anchor tag and get rid of the javascript href crap.