# How to hide href from appearing in the bottom of browser window

Tags: javascript, href, statusbar

I am executing some javascript on clicking on anchor tags and use `href="javascript:void(null);"` to disable anchor tag.

Now if I hover on anchor tag browser status bar will show `javascript:void(null)`.

Is there any way hiding it from status bar?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207467/how-to-hide-links-on-browsers-statusbar-when-you-mouseover-on-links-on-webpage

Comment: Why are you using an anchor in the first place if it doesn't link anywhere? You could simply use a span or whatever, with `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: I have used in entire site.  changing anchor tag to span will be a huge task. :(

Comment: In that case you could just remove the `href` attribute altogether

Answer (score 1):

Use events instead of the href attribute.
Example with jQuery:

```
<a href="#" id="link">I'm a link</a>

$('a#link').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    .... 
    do whatever you want
    ....
});
```

EDIT:
For the sake of completeness here is a pure JavaScript solution as mentioned in the comments below:

```
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    // other stuff 
};
```

Comment: No jQuery. Use javascript method.

Comment: It's the same : `document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); // other stuff }; `